# How to remove the last statement in a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to construct a statement (because the client requests for it) and want to remove the last statement in a for loop but still included in between the loop.

This is what I am trying to achieve (as a broad example as I can):
**I selected: 2 years period, 2 yrs period, 1 years period, 1 yrs period.**

I managed to achieve this but at the very end, it doesn't end with a period, it ended with a comma instead.

The number of years is selected by the user, therefore I declared a variable.

Here is my code in Javascript:

```
    var out_content = document.getElementById("content");
    var in_year = 2;
    var in_period = ["years","yrs"];
    var sText = "I selected: ";
    for (var i=0;i<in_year; in_year--)
    {
        for (var p=0;p<in_period.length;p++)
        {
            sText += in_year + in_period[p];
            sText += ",";
        }
    }

out_content.innerHTML = sText;
```

What do I do?

Comment: `for (var i=0;i<in_year; in_year--)` <-- I don't believe it works

Comment: @zerkms Why not? It's a bit of an awkward way, but it should work.

Comment: @zerkms I do, since you are changing the loop every time and at some point `i === in_year`. Its not advised though, better to increment `i :)`

Comment: Oh god, it's the other way around: not the counter but the boundary is shifted. That's impressive

Comment: if you don't want the comma at the end of the string, you could delete it after the loop or replace it with what you do want at the end.

Comment: @zerkms it works. no doubt about it. Awkward, yes. But that's what the client wants the display to look like. _meh_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve your problem is to just remove the last character (the unwanted comma) and put a period there instead.

```
sText.slice(0,-1)+'.'
```

Slicing from 0 to -1 means getting the characters from the beginning to the one before the last.

Comment: Easiest method I've ever seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the last character from your string, when predictable, can be easily achieved as such:

```
sText = sText.substring(0, sText.length-2);
```

Substring takes two parameters, start (`0`) and end (you want `length minus 1` here, but since its viewed as an array you might want `length - 2`). Heres more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: I believe this best way to achieve this . As other methods may vary from browser to browser

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle this kind of problem is to use an array, then join array elements:

```
var sText = "I selected: ";
var aText = [];
for (var i=0;i<in_year; in_year--)
{
    for (var p=0;p<in_period.length;p++)
    {
        aText.push(in_year + in_period[p]);
    }
}

sText += aText.join() + '.';
```

Comment: But then how do you add the commas and how can you tell it to replace a comma to a period at the last string?

Comment: The `join` method adds the comma and there's no need to replace the last, because it's just not here :) I edited my post to add the trailing dot.

Answer (score 0):

Add the if statement before comma and check with the variable value with p and the condition should pass but should fail on last loop statement